# Stetho and chrome:inspect pending REST petitions

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, android-debug, stetho

I'm using Stetho, Retrofit and OkHttp with Chrome Developer Tools for debug purposes, all seems to work OK, I see my local database content, I can inspect my UI, but if I do some REST petitions to my server with the Network Inspection enabled the petitions remains as "Pending", but if I copy the URL and paste on a Chrome tab the petition executes correctly and I don't know what is happening.

[image]

These are my gradle imports:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'

implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.5.0'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer here
https://github.com/facebook/stetho/issues/346

I accidentally used a regular interceptor instead of a network interceptor.

So this is my **WRONG** version

```
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
        httpClient.addInterceptor(new StethoInterceptor());
```

And this is the **CORRECT** version:

```
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
        httpClient.addNetworkInterceptor(new StethoInterceptor());
```

Comment: Since you are already using stetho, you can remove the okhttp interceptor - httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);